# .NET MVC and SalesForce drop down list issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, forms, salesforce

1. I built a form in sales force and
   added it to my site. The whole goal
   of this is that the form on my site
   submits to sales force.
2. I want to
   add server-side validation to my
   form like I have on other forms on
   my site.
3. Sales force uses a weird
   name for drop down lists that often
   starts with a number. In my case,
   the drop down list input name="33N80563003V2aX"

This is giving me an issue because, as I understand it, the name of the property in my model has to match the name of the input control on the .aspx page. However, I can't have the name of my property start with a number.

```
//In my .aspx page: 
Name: 
<%= Html.TextBox("name", Model.Name, new { tabindex = 1 })%>

Type of Issue: 
<%= Html.DropDownList("33N80563003V2aX", Model.33N80563003V2aX, "--None--", new { tabindex = 2 })%>
```

---

```
//In my model: (does not compile because of the name)
public string Name { get; set; }
public SelectList 33N80563003V2aX { get; set; }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it... why do you HAVE to use that input name? Can you show us some more code - like how the model is populated and how the model is validated and then submitted to sales force? Cheers.

Comment: I don't know .NET MVC, but if you could handcraft the data sent by POST to Salesforce, maybe via some form submission handler... You'd just have to go through your form fields, urlencode values and create string to be sent?

Comment: If you form posts to SalesForce, why would you bother validating it? Client slide validation will surely be enough? Salesforce will validate it server side when you post it to them.

Comment: @Charlino: I have to use that input name because that's how SalesForce forms work. I build a form on SF, they give me the html (with input names they are expecting on form submit), then I put that on my site and it posts data into salesforce. Pretty easy despite the problem I had.

Comment: @Bigfellahull: I didn't say this in the original post, but I wanted server side validation because we keep some of the posted information on our servers as well. It's not just doing validation, it's doing some saving as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We built a similar solution interfacing .NET and Salesforce.com. There are two ways to implement - one is to post directly to Salesforce.com, and the other is to proxy the request, like you are doing, so you can do validation and other stuff. Since you are proxying the request, your form doesn't have to match Salesforce.com requirements at all.

You should collect all the data, then use the .NET HTTP objects assemble a post to Salesforce.com with whatever param names they require. You can then call your dropdown "glurm" or whatever you want, as you'll be repackaging the data for sending to Salesforce.com

Comment: Ahh that makes a lot more sense than what I ended up doing (ugly workaround) thanks!!